# Python code to create a diagram of Failure Assessment Diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I would like to do a Monte Carlo Probabilistic Model in Structural Analysis. In order to do so, I need to graph this model:

[image: FAD]

I worked out following code, but it still needs a lot of work:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import arange
%matplotlib inline

# define the true objective function
def objective(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return (a * x) + (b * x**2) + (c * x**3) + (d * x**4) + (e * x**5) + f

y = np.array([1,0.99,0.97,0.93,0.9,0.81,0.7,0.57,0.5,0.32,0.25])
x = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.67,.8,0.9,1.0,1.05,1.2,1.32])

popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
a, b, c, d, e, f = popt
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 0.1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c, d, e, f)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

[image: try]

1. Can you help me do the code properly to create a curve_fit?
2. How can I determine whether a random number will be inside the curve?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the curve to attach to the Y axis on the left, one way would be to set the X axis minimum to be the same as the smallest X axis value that you have (in this case, zero).  [matplotlib.pyplot.xlim](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

   To close the right side of the plot, you can plot a vertical line based on the min/max of your data set.  [matplotlib.pyplot.vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html)
2. While perhaps an overly simplistic view of your problem, one way would be to simply compare the value in question to the ranges of your dataset.
   `min(y) <= a[1] <= max(y)`

The following code shows each example, but doesn't take the time to make it necessarily as Pythonic as it could be (written literally for illustration).

***Code:***

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from numpy import arange
# %matplotlib inline

# define the true objective function
def objective(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return (a * x) + (b * x**2) + (c * x**3) + (d * x**4) + (e * x**5) + f

y = np.array([1,0.99,0.97,0.93,0.9,0.81,0.7,0.57,0.5,0.32,0.25])
x = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.67,.8,0.9,1.0,1.05,1.2,1.32])

popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
a, b, c, d, e, f = popt
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 0.1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c, d, e, f)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')


# Set X axis limits 
pyplot.xlim(min(x),)

# Set Y axis limits 
pyplot.ylim(0,)

# Close the curve on the right
pyplot.vlines(max(x), min(y), 0, linestyles='--', color='red')

# Value within range?
a = (0.15, 0.63)

a1 = min(x) <= a[0] <= max(x)
a2 = min(y) <= a[1] <= max(y)
if a1 and a2:
    print('True')

# Plot test point
pyplot.plot(a[0], a[1], marker='o', markersize=5, color="blue")

pyplot.show()
```

***Output:***
[image: Example FAD Output]

***Shell output:***  `True`